# Cucucmber Maven: Execute a logic after generating the test report

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

Iam using cucumber maven for creating my test automation framework.
After the test execution completes cucumber reports.json will be generated.
I have to get some failure informations from this json file and send this failures to splunk.

For that I can extract the necessary details what i want is from that cucumber.json file.
But where can i include that inplementation in my automation framework?
Cucumber.json will be generate only after finishing the test execution. 
As per my requirement once the cucumber.json generates , get the necessary failure details from the json and send that details
to spunk..

Is it possible to do it with the help of maven-surefire-plugin.In the below SendFailure class written
the logic for extracting the details from generated json and send details to splunk.I hope it will execute
after the test execution finishes. But it is not working.

Please suggest a suitable way to handle this.

My requirement is once the cucumber.json generates I have to get some details from that json .
At present Iam confused to where to call this logic?

```
<build>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.send.SendFailure</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question is. I modified my pom file as follows and it worked

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.send.SendFailure</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
     </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this has been solved yet. My solution for this was (a couple of years ago) to call an external (python) script. And in that script wait for the file to exist and then do something with it.

At that time I did not find a way to do it from within the tests.

Also may be worth considering adding the json as a resource in splunk, and do the querying there.